# Isomorphism between tensor of module's dual and Hom(M,-)

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

For an $A$-module $M$, how can I show that the homomorphism

$M^* \bigotimes N \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(M,N)$

is an isomorphism when $M=A^k$ or $N=A^k$?

Where $M^*$ denotes the dual of $M$ and $k \geq 0$.

Comment: For example, can you prove this if $M=A$ or if $N=A$?

Comment: If $M=A$ then $M^* = Hom(A,A)$ which is $A$, so the map is from $A \bigotimes N \rightarrow Hom(A,N)$, is that right? What do I do after that? And how is it different for $N=A$?

Comment: Well, you'll have to think about that for a while. Use the definition of the map you are given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a canonical bilinear map $f\colon M^*\times N\to\operatorname{Hom}(M,N)$, defined by
$$
f(\xi,y)\colon x\mapsto \xi(x)y
$$
This bilinear map defines a homomorphism $\varphi\colon M^*\otimes N\to\operatorname{Hom}(M,N)$ which is generally not an isomorphism. For instance, if $A=\mathbb{Z}$, $M=N=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, the domain is the zero module and the codomain is (isomorphic to) $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

However, if $M=A^k$, the map $\varphi$ is indeed an isomorphism, because of the commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
(A^k)^*\otimes N @>>> \operatorname{Hom}(A^k,N) \\
@VVV @VVV \\
N^k @>>> N^k
\end{CD}
$$
where the bottom arrow is the identity and the two vertical isomorphisms are readily written out.

For $N=A^k$, consider that $M^*\otimes A^k\cong (M^*)^k$ and also $\operatorname{Hom}(M,A^k)\cong\operatorname{Hom}(M,A)^k$ (again, easy isomorphisms to write).

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I wasn't going to add details: I consider these hints more than enough to push the OP on the right track.

Comment: Sure, it's more than enough. ;)